# Unable to use DateTime.Now in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using VB.net in VS 2013.  I am trying to use `DateTime.Now` to retrieve the current date and time.  When I enter this into the Immediate window, I receive this message:

`DateTime is not declared.  It may be innaccessible due to its protection level.`

What do I need to do?

Comment: It sounds like Josh Part knows why it's failing in your particular situation.  In general though, you don't have to qualify it as `DateTime.Now`, `Date.Now`, or even `Now()` in VB.NET (these are all synonyms).  Just use `Now` for the general case.

Comment: Thanks but I need the time stamp too

Comment: Thanks.  If I enter ?Now in the Immediate window, I get the message "Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized"

Comment: It's the same.  In VB.NET, `DateTime` is just an alias for `Date`, which contains both sets of information.

Comment: Please show the code that is actually failing.

Comment: This is the line of code:  Sr.write("closing " & e.contract.symbol & " " & Now).  I have a break point on this line.  When I try to step through I get  "DateAndTime.vb" not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.DateTime.Now`

Out of local variables, both Immediate Window and Command Window require the fully qualified name.

Comment: Thanks.  When I try to enter this in the immediate window, I get the message "Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized"

Comment: I have a line with Now in there and when I try to step through this line of code, I get "DateAndTime.vb" not found.